# How to force remote-only reads in Cassandra3?

Tags: java, database, cassandra, benchmarking, cassandra-3.0

We are trying to modify the Cassandra code to perform ONLY remote reads (never read locally) for performance testing purposes of the Speculative Retry and Request Duplication latency reduction techniques.

So far we have modified 
src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/AbstractReadExecutor.java
to do something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractReadExecutor {
  protected int getNonLocalEndpointIndex (Iterable<InetAddress> endpoints) {
    int endpoint_index = 0;

    // iterate thru endpoints and pick non-local one
    boolean found = false;
    for (InetAddress e : endpoints) {
     if (! StorageProxy.canDoLocalRequest(e) ) {
        found = true;
        break;
     }
     endpoint_index++;
    }

    if (!found) {
        endpoint_index = 0;
    }
    return endpoint_index;
   }
}


public static class NeverSpeculatingReadExecutor extends AbstractReadExecutor {
   public void executeAsync() {
         int endpoint_index = getNonLocalEndpointIndex(targetReplicas);
         makeDataRequests(targetReplicas.subList(endpoint_index, endpoint_index+1));

         if (targetReplicas.size() > 1)
             makeDigestRequests(targetReplicas.subList(1, targetReplicas.size()));
         }
    }
}
```

However, it does not work since targetReplicas is almost always just 1 endpoint (the local one) for using small workloads, 5 cassandra nodes, and a replication factor of 3.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for testing, can set 1 node to be in wrong DC and use LOCAL queries for things that that node does not own (white list load balancing policy on driver to ensure requests go to only it). Just need to make it so only test for things that node doesn't own a copy of.

Or are you interested in doing things like testing the proxy mutations in the read repairs?

Comment: Yes I think this could work as well! I think my new code solution below works without modifying the testbed

Answer (score 0):

I was able to only do remote-reads by adding a function "getRemoteReplicas()" that filters out the local nodes before/when the ReadExecutor object is created. consistencyLevel.filterForQuery() then usually just returns 1 node (a non-local one).

```
public static AbstractReadExecutor getReadExecutor(...) {
    ...
    List<InetAddress> remoteReplicas = getRemoteReplicas( allReplicas );
    List<InetAddress> targetReplicas = consistencyLevel.filterForQuery(keyspace, remoteReplicas, repairDecision);
    ...
}

private static List<InetAddress> getRemoteReplicas(List<InetAddress> replicas) {
    logger.debug("ALL REPLICAS: " + replicas.toString());
    List<InetAddress> remote_replicas = new ArrayList<>();

    // iterate thru replicas and pick non-local one
    boolean found = false;
    for (InetAddress r : replicas) {
        if (! StorageProxy.canDoLocalRequest(r) ) {
            remote_replicas.add(r);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
      return replicas;
    }
    logger.debug("REMOTE REPLICAS: " + remote_replicas.toString());
    return remote_replicas;
}
```

in src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/AbstractReadExecutor.java